# Azure Search - giving our clients what they need with regard to scores/ranks - percentage match

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We've been using Azure Search as our production search service for a couple months now, and our clients are starting to voice concerns about flexibility in ranking and scoring - the TF-IDF ratios are meaningless to them (which I can understand) and they are used to seeing *percentage* matches from their prior vendors.

It's important to understand that our clients mainly query on people's names. These people's names exist in our records both in their own field, as well as in an additional field of unstructured text.  When they query on John Anderson, for example, they are looking for records with a certain percentage match to the name John Anderson.  They are less concerned with how many times John Anderson appears in the document.

What they want is to be able to customize their results so that, for example, only results with "90% match or higher" to the queried name is returned.  We have no idea where to start with this because the only thing we see Azure Search offering us is TF-IDF scoring.  How can we convert our understanding of the results to percentage match vs term frequency, which we really aren't concerned with?  Can Azure Search handle this?  If we've gotten this far along into choosing it as our production search service and we can't present results to our clients in the manner they were accustomed from the vendors they left, they will leave us, and I unfortunately am going to lose my job...

MS Azure Search personnel... please help!

Comment: Can you be more specific with how you want to score? What does it mean to have a "90% match"?
There's no way to disable TF/IDF-based scoring, but in some cases there may be ways to model the way you want to boost things. If you could share the specific way you have in mind for computing stores we can see how can we approximate it.

Comment: Hi @PabloCastro  to start with a high-level simple example:  a client searches on "John Anderson".  Any documents with that exact phrase, "John Anderson" would be considered a 100% match.  We don't care how many time it shows up in the record.  If we have a record with "John A. Anderson" or "John G. Anderson," we'd call that along the lines of a 98% match, based on the fact that both terms appears, are in proximity, but are separated by a character, thus lose 2%.  Then if we had a result of "Kevin John Anderson" that would be more around 80-90% match based on the additional work being present

Comment: The exact rules could be defined by our development, but we would still need guidance on how to implement them.  Thanks.

Comment: @Stpete111 It sounds like your notion of % match lines up with edit distance... Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: @BruceJohnston I'm not positive on that.  In my example above of Kevin John Anderson, "John" and "Anderson" are the same distance apart as in just plain John Anderson, but we would definitely expect the percentage match to be lower on a record with Kevin John Anderson than on a record with John Anderson.  Does edit distance consider additional words like that, or only the distance between the query terms?

Comment: @Stpete111 That depends on how you define what the term is. If you're searching for "John Anderson" as a single term, then "Kevin John Anderson" is an edit distance of 6 away. If "John" and "Anderson" are separate terms, then edit distance doesn't really apply. I'm asking as a way to try to understand your requirement; To be clear, Azure Search doesn't support ranking by edit distance.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and propose a few options given the brief description in the comments above:

Assuming you're really focused on people name lookups and have a set of specific rules to model, perhaps you can use different matching rules with different boosts. You'll need to use the [full Lucene query syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search) for this (use queryType=full in the query string).

For simple cases, you can start by discriminating cases where matches are contiguous versus when they are not: if the input search is "John Anderson", you can rewrite it into:

```
"John Anderson"^100 OR (John AND Anderson)
```

Which would heavily polarize results and return things in the order you described. If you want to limit how much token-level edit distance until it's not a match you can use slot in phrases:

```
"John Anderson"^100 OR "John Anderson"~2
```

If you also want to handle cases where an extra term entirely before or entirely after impacts the match, I wonder if you could use prefixes/suffixes. For example, during indexing you add the word "begin" before the name and "end" after (you can use a more random sequence of letter that's unlikely to be a name). So if the field value was "John Anderson", then the field should have "begin John Anderson end". Then at search time you can do:

```
"begin John Anderson end"^1000 OR "John Anderson"^100 OR "John Anderson"~2
```

This will favor matches from beginning to end of the name, followed by infix matches of the name in exact sequence, followed by names with the original tokens plus other stuff in the middle. You can reshuffle the order by adjusting the boosts.

Following this will give you roughly the order you want, but not the percentages. To calculate percentages you could map them from the orders of magnitudes in scores, and/or by post-processing the results against the original search terms.

Comment: Pablo and Bruce, thanks for the detailed answer.  I will review these suggestions with my developer and will revert as soon as possible with additional questions I'm sure.